# Variance of random matrix?

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, symmetric-matrices, stochastic-matrices

Let's say $W$ is a symmetric matrix random variable, i.e., $W=W_{ij}$ with probability $P_{ij}$. We already know the definition of $\mathbf{E}[W]$. Is there a definition for $\mathbf{Var}[W]$? And does any relationship between $\mathbf{Var}[W], \mathbf{E}[W]$ and $\mathbf{E}[W^TW]$ exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what the distribution of your matrix $W$ is.

Comment: Indeed, there is a definition of the variance matrix (or covariance matrix).  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)